# Достать ID из одной таблицы SUM() + MAX()

Tags: oracle

Есть таблица:

```
ID(pk)    ID_2     sum
1         1        111
2         1        523
3         3        521
4         2        255
5         7        221
6         11        22
```

Нужно достать ID_2, но при этом сначала вычислить SUM() с группировкой по ID_2, затем найти MAX() из этих суммированных результатов, и достать ID_2.

Написал следующую дичь. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
SELECT id
    FROM (
             SELECT SUM(sum) as sumz, ID_2 as id FROM tableX GROUP BY ID_2)
    WHERE sumz = (SELECT MAX(sumz)
                  FROM (
                           SELECT SUM(sum) as sumz, id_2 as id FROM tableX GROUP BY id_2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id_2
FROM tableX
GROUP BY id_2
ORDER BY SUM(sum) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

?